# First steps with amd64 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, lookup

I try to learn amd64 assembler. This is the first thing I tried. This piece of assembly should replicate the functionality of the following piece of C code, which turns a binary sha-256 hash into a human readable form.

#### assembly code

```
1:  .ascii "0123456789abcdef"
    .global show_hash
show_hash:
    .type show_hash @function
    .func show_hash
    mov $32,%ecx
    .p2align 2
0:  xor %eax,%eax
    lodsb
    mov %eax,%edx
    shr $4,%al
    and $15,%dl
    mov 1b(%rax),%al
    mov 1b(%rdx),%dl
    mov %bl,%ah
    stosw
    dec %ecx
    jnz 0b
    mov %cl,(%rdi)
    ret
    .endfunc
```

#### C code

```
void show_hash(char *dst, unsigned char *src) {
  static const char *lookup = "0123456789abcdef";
  char lo, hi, byte;
  int i = 32;

  do {
    byte = *src++;
    hi = lookup[byte >> 4];
    lo = lookup[byte & 0xf];
    *dst++ = hi;
    *dst++ = lo;
  } while (i--);
}
```

Am I doing it right? I tried to move the lookup table (label `1`) into `.section rodata`, but all references to it were changed to `0` in the linked program, so I put it into the text section for now.

Comment: I don't think you can access data unless it's in the data segment.

Comment: @Hawken How do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: all memory is referenced using the segment specified by `%ds` or if it's on the stack, `%ss`. Unless you have personally set the segment register, `mov %cs,%ds`, or your assembler is adding a custom segment offset, you can't read from outside `.data`. I don't know if modern OSs allow you to read from `.text` at all even if you did.

Comment: @Hawken You see that this code is written for x86-64 linux which uses a flat memory modell? All segment registers except %fs and %gs which serve a special purpose are set to zero.

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that. http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64 contains information on this for anyone else who did not know.

Comment: Okay. My bad. This code really is x86 code, but nevertless it is written for linux. Linux, in a similar way as most x86 operating systems today, does not use segmentation (except for some special threading related concepts). All segment registers are set to zero; all accesses to memory are done in the same address space.

Comment: In 64bit it would seem that it's required, so you were right, I should have known. I'm currently writing 16bit x86 assembly without an OS where segmentation is *needed* to address your full 20bit address space. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's correct:

- <strike>If `show_hash` uses [cdecl calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) you should preserve registers like `%bl`, and read the input parameter values from the stack into esi and edi.</strike>
  (see section "3.2.3 Parameter Passing" of [the Application Binary Interface](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf): parameters are conveniently passed in the rdi and rsi registers)
- <strike>I don't understand the syntax of `mov 1b(%rax),%al`: is it reading from the `lookup` array defined at label `1:`? On re-reading, I think it is; however that will only work if the most-significant bytes of rax and rdx are all zero; perhaps you should initialize them as you did using `xor %eax,%eax`</strike>
  (apparently `xor %eax,%eax` will clear the whole of `%rax`)
- You're using `stosw` which writes two bytes (two ASCII characters) a time; but `%ah` contains  a value from `%bl`, and `%bl` wasn't previously initialized? I think that statement should have been `mov %dl,%ah` not `mov %bl,%ah`; or perhaps you could have done `mov 1b(%rdx),%ah` directly.
- The function ends with `mov %cl,(%rdi)` to null-terminate the string; that is clever but could use a comment (it took me a bit to figure out). Most of the [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) questions either have good comments, or answer which say that they should have good comments.

Comment: xor %eax,%eax implicitly zeroes out the upper 32 bits of %rax as well. Second, this is x86_64 assembly on Linux. The calling convention is different; the first couple of arguments are actually passed in registers. I think I accidentially switched %dl with %bl, but I'm not very sury.

Comment: I asked this question almost a year ago; I'm not really sure about most parts anymore.

Comment: In that case the only error I see is the typo involving `%bl` instead of `%dl`.